# Problem creating subscriptions on Replication Server version 15.7.1

Tags: replication, sybase, sybase-ase

if anyone knows what is the error? `Can not use active or standby connection names for subscriptions` 
I got this error when I'm trying to create my subscriptions. I have already created a repdef `WITH PRIMARY AT pb1.customer` and when I tried to run my subscription, `WITH REPLICATE AT pb2.customer`. It is showing the error. I have also created a logical connection `pb1.customer` for dump/load db.

pb1 and pb2 are both ASE, ASE15.5 and ASE15.7 respectively.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates you're using a WarmStandby (WS) setup, in which case there are no subscriptions required (nor supported), period.

If you're trying to use the WS pair as a source for replicating into a 3rd db, then the repdef will need to reference the WS logical pair as the primary db.

If you're trying to replicate into the WS pair from a 3rd db, then the subscription will reference the WS logical pair as the replicate db.

Comment: I don't get it. Currently my WS setup only involving with 2 ASE DBs (let's say pb1.customer and pb2.customer; pb1 is my primary db whereas pb2 is my replicate db) and I have created 1 logical connection in my primary db. I created my connection of replicate db using dump marker. I don't have a 3rd db in my situation. My aim is just to make sure that primary data can be replicated into my replicate db after dump/load db action. Is that mean I don't need to actually create repedf/subs on primary to make sure data can be replicated into my replicate db? I'm very confused about WS setup.

Comment: WS doesn't use repdef/sub; you create a logical connection, add PDB as 'active' component of WS, add RDB as 'standby' component of WS, mark the PDB, and replication should occur for everything that's been marked for rep; repdef/sub is used for MSA and table-level rep; repdef/sub is also used if replicating into or out-of WS (from/to a 3rd db)

Comment: Step1: Create logical connection to PDB `create logical connection to pb1.customer`. Step2: Create dump marker in my RDB connection `create connection to pb2.customer
set error class to rs_sqlserver_error_class
set function string class to rs_sqlserver_function_class
set username to <maint_user>
set password to <maint_pass>
with log transfer on
as standby for pb1.customer
use dump marker`. Is my connection to RDB above is created correctly?

Comment: As you mentioned, <adding PDB (pb1.customer) as 'active' and RDB as 'standby' component of WS>, is that mean in my RDB connection above I should do something like `as active for pb1.customer` and `as standby for pb2.customer`? Both `as active for` and `as standby for` can be included in the same create connection command above?

Comment: Hi @markp, is there any advice could provide for my situation?

Comment: 'as active' and 'as standby' are mutually exclusive; you need 2x 'create connection' commands ... one for pdb/'as active' ... one for rdb/'as standby'

Comment: But currently, my PDB connections are used for ASE-ORA replications. Will it affect my ASE-ORA replications if I create a new connection for pdb using 'as active'?

Comment: this doesn't make sense, first you say your WS is setup for ASE-ASE, now you say you're doing ASE-Oracle but also want to do ASE-ASE; I can't tell if you're talking about different setups or the same setup but you're confusing terminology; if you want ASE1-ASE2 and ASE1-Oracle, and you insist on using WS, then you need to setup WS for ASE1-ASE2 first, then you setup replication from WS/logical connection to Oracle

Comment: Yes, ASE1-ORA replications have already setup for a few years ago and this connection has a lot of repdef/subs built on it. Last 2 weeks, I am being requested to setup ASE1-ASE2 replications. I need to make sure this 2 ASE1-ASE2 are synced after dump/load db action, so I am thinking to use dump marker in my ASE2 connection and use WS approach to get these things done. Did I misunderstand something wrong? Shouldn't I use WS setup? Please advise.

Comment: you can't build WS on top of ASE-Oracle; you may be able to use MSA to replicate ASE1-ASE2